# Google Fonts blocking css resources

Tags: css, wordpress, blocking

When i test my website https://www.groupe-cph.com in google page speed insight

it said i have 1 blocking css resources

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script%3A300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CLato%3A300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CLato%3A300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C900%2C900italic&subset=latin&ver=4.9.3

and im using Autoptimize , How i can solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to get rid of blocking CSS resource when using Google Fonts, there is one way to do it with Autoptimize.

1. In Autoptimize, select Extra tab, tick Remove Google Fonts.
2. Copy [all content in Google Fonts link](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing%20Script%3A300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CLato%3A300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C900%2C900italic%7CLato%3A300%2C300italic%2C400%2C400italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C900%2C900italic&subset=latin&ver=4.9.3) above, paste to your style.css files. Save it.
3. Done

**Pros**:

- You get rid of blocking CSS resource.
- You save 1 request for your visitor.

**Cons**:

You have to do all above step again if you want to change another Google Fonts.